# Keydown Event to save locally using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a basic online editing interface for coursework. I would like to save the content of my `#textarea` div every time there's a `keydown` event. The code works partially but I can't edit the text without the cursor going to the top of the div.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', saveLocally);

const saveLocally = function() {
  let areaText = document.getElementById("textArea");
  console.log(areaText);
  let text = document.getElementById("textArea").innerHTML;
  console.log(text);
  let localData;

  localStorage.setItem('siteData', text);
  localData = localStorage.getItem('siteData');

  console.log(localData);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('siteData'));

  areaText.innerHTML = localData;
}
```

```html
<div id="inputArea">
  <div id="textArea" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you immediately update the `innerText` of the element after someone types. This affects the cursor as the node contents are changed. You don't need to do this anyway, so the line can be removed.

You instead need to perform the logic which retrieves the value from localStorage when the page *loads*. Also note that you should use the `keyup` event instead of `keydown`, otherwise you'll not save the last key which was pressed. Try this:

```html
<div id="inputArea">
  <div id="textArea" contenteditable="true"></div>
</div>
```

```js
let areaText = document.getElementById("textArea");

const saveLocally = function() {
  let text = areaText.innerHTML;
  localStorage.setItem('siteData', text);
}

const retrieveSavedText = function() {
  var text = localStorage.getItem('siteData');
  areaText.innerHTML = text;
}

document.addEventListener('keyup', saveLocally);
retrieveSavedText();
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/7tg8znk9/)